# Python - Generate random number from custom time

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

So say that I generate a random number using `random.random()` on one system without a custom seed, but say that I wanted to also generate a random number ahead of time so that if I were to use `random.random()` at that time without seeding it would return the same number. In essence, *"predict"* the random number. How might I customize the time that random uses to seed itself? I thought to do the following based on how the random module seeds:

```
import random
import time

print random.random()
random.seed(long(time.time()*256))
print random.random()
```

However, that gave me separate numbers and I don't understand why. Should they not be done at the same instance in time?

**tl;dr**

How can I customize `random.seed(x)` where it would seed at a custom point in time.

Assume that `random.random()` is called a-new each time so it is the first number being generated, and not the second, third, fourth, etc.

Note that I do not want to do this in the past, so not get the state and then restore it, but be able to generate what will be generated in the future.

**CLARIFICATION:** The system this will be used on does not have urandom implemented.

Comment: the "time" in this instance is just a number used to seed, there is nothing temporal about python's built in PRNG.

Comment: If python is not given a seed then it generates it based off the current time since the epoch.

Comment: Also note that starting in Python 2.4 "If randomness sources are provided by the operating system, they are used instead of the system time" (from https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) which is basically done for the sole purpose of making what you are trying to do impossible (or at least very hard)

Comment: ^ assuming the system it is used on has urandom then it does, otherwise it is based off of time.time() not the operating system time, and as said above the system does not have urandom implemented

Comment: I think it's impossible to to what you are trying to do, mostly because there's a small delay in the time module, a fraction of milliseconds that enough to render the prediction impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was wrong.

It's possible to do it:
Here's how:

```
import time
import random

def predicite_future(delay):
    random.seed(long(time.time() + delay) * 256)
    return random.random()

delay = 10

print "The next value will be:",predicite_future(delay)
print "Waiting for %s seconds"%delay
time.sleep(delay)
random.seed(long(time.time()) * 256)
print "As predicited, the value is:",random.random()
```

output:

```
The next value will be: 0.359211550742
Waiting for 10 seconds
As predicited, the value is: 0.359211550742
```

Comment: You just seeded with the same number twice. try doing it without seeding in `predicite_future`

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually do have a `urandom` of sorts or at the very least the following does *not* throw an exception

```
from binascii import hexlify as _hexlify
from os import urandom as _urandom
a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(16)), 16)
```

does it?

Now assuming that lets modify the random lib which can be found [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r27a4/Lib/random.py).

first replace

```
    if a is None:
        try:
            a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(16)), 16)
        except NotImplementedError:
            import time
            a = long(time.time() * 256) # use fractional seconds
```

with just

```
    if a is None:
        import time
        a = long(time.time() * 256) # use fractional seconds
        print ("bottom - the seed is", a) # debug
```

Now in bottom of the file in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` remove the test and instead put

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from time import time
    then1 = long(time() * 256)
    from random import random, seed
    then2 = long(time() * 256)
    assert then1 == then2 # if fails here the time has changed

    print random() # unseeded
    seed(then1)
    print random() # use the seed with think it uses
```

Now assume the time we want to predict is `d` in the future then we could have `then1 = long((time()+d) * 256)` to predict a result of `random.random()` in the future.